# R: do.call with merge and eapply

Tags: r, merge, xts, quantmod

I am merging two xts objects with join="left" i.e. (all rows in the left object, and those that match in the right). I loaded these objectd in myEnv.

```
library(quantmod)
myEnv <- new.env()
getSymbols("AAPL;FB", env=myEnv)
[1] "AAPL" "FB"  
MainXTS <- do.call(merge, c(eapply(myEnv, Cl), join = "left"))
head(MainXTS)
           AAPL.Close FB.Close
2007-01-03   2.992857       NA
2007-01-04   3.059286       NA
2007-01-05   3.037500       NA
2007-01-08   3.052500       NA
2007-01-09   3.306072       NA
2007-01-10   3.464286       NA
range(index(myEnv$AAPL))
[1] "2007-01-03" "2020-10-27"
range(index(myEnv$FB))
[1] "2012-05-18" "2020-10-27"
```

So far it is working as expected since the time index in above merged object is being picked up from APPL. The issue is that when I change the order of the tickers so that FB comes first, the merged object still picks up time indexes from AAPL.

```
myEnv <- new.env()
getSymbols("FB;AAPL", env=myEnv)
[1] "FB"   "AAPL"
MainXTS <- do.call(merge, c(eapply(myEnv, Cl), join = "left"))
head(MainXTS)
           AAPL.Close FB.Close
2007-01-03   2.992857       NA
2007-01-04   3.059286       NA
2007-01-05   3.037500       NA
2007-01-08   3.052500       NA
2007-01-09   3.306072       NA
2007-01-10   3.464286       NA
```

I was expecting the time index to be picked up from FB. Does any one know what I am missing?

I think this has something to do with the fact that the order of objects being loaded is the same and in both cases above it is:

```
ls(myEnv)
[1] "AAPL" "FB"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can change the order with `match`

```
out <-  do.call(merge, c(lapply(mget(ls(myEnv)[match(ls(myEnv),
        c("FB", "AAPL"))], myEnv), Cl), join = "left"))
```

-output

```
head(out)
#           FB.Close AAPL.Close
#2012-05-18    38.23   18.94214
#2012-05-21    34.03   20.04571
#2012-05-22    31.00   19.89179
#2012-05-23    32.00   20.37714
#2012-05-24    33.03   20.19000
#2012-05-25    31.91   20.08178
```